# How to set javaagent in intellij idea VM Options?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, filepath, stackify

I am using Intellij Idea for development.
I want to add log monitoring using

https://stackify.com/prefix/

and I am following their guide on setting javaagent from the below link

http://support.stackify.com/hc/en-us/articles/211497443-How-to-Enable-Java-Profiling-with-Prefix

[image: intellij vm options]

When I run the project , I am getting the following error

[image: javaagent error]

IIntellij is reading the path till the first space only.

Kindly help me solve the issue.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried escaping the spaces?

Comment: @Makoto no I havent. Which escape character is acceped for vm options for space?

Comment: I'm on Linux so I wouldn't entirely know for Windows, but I've used backslash.  You may want to reference how to escape spaces in Windows paths, though.

Comment: @Makoto tried backslash and ^ . Still  reading till first space

Comment: "c:\Program Files (x86)\Stackify..." ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should put the file path in double quotes :

```
-javaagent:"C:\Program Files (x86)\StackifyPrefix\java\lib\stackify-java-sprn.jar"
```

Comment: How to use it from a dynamic path? i.e %AppData%

Answer (score 10):

Double quotes method explained by bowmore didn't work for me, had to go the slash way:

```
-javaagent:C:/Program Files (x86)/StackifyPrefix/java/lib/stackify-java-sprn.jar
```

Comment: How about on Linux

Comment: Try escaping spaces with backslashes

Comment: How to use it from a dynamic path? i.e %AppData%